# Adding another Table

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

Okay so I have made a report calculating how many contracts are funded in each month within the year 2014.

So Now I have to calculate the total for all the contracts that are in SERVICE ONLY.

What I mean by this is I have a table called tlkOrigDept. Within that table I have this

```
  Table tlkOrigDept

  orig_dept_id         Orig_Dept_Name
      1                    Sales
      2                   Service
      3                    F&I
      4                   Other
      5                   Direct Marketing
```

So I have to get all the funded contracts ONLY that from  SERVICE which is  'orig_dept_id' = 2 So this is my Query but the problem I see is in my where clause. Because when I change the orig_dept_Id to 3 it works but not for 2. It just shows blank and not an error message.

The user inputs a @Begin_date and @End_Date the User than picks a company which is @Program. The user should see ALL the FUNDED Contracts for each month that are from SERVICE ONLY.

I either see a problem in the SELECT Statement or my WHERE Clause

Here is my Query

```
[code="sql"]    

Alter Proc spGetAdminServiceYTD

 (@Begin_Date  DATETIME, 
  @End_Date DATETIME,
  @program int=null) As

 Declare @year int
 Set @year = 2014

 Declare @orig_dept_ID Int
 Set @orig_dept_ID = 2


  Begin


    SELECT  d.name, a.dealer_code, b.last_name, b.city, b.state, b.phone,e.orig_dept_name
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.orig_dept_id) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) January
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.orig_dept_id) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) Feburary
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) March
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) April
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) May
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) June
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) July
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) August
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) September
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) October
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) November
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) December
        , count(1) As YTD      




  FROM tdealer a 
         JOIN tContact b ON a.contact_id = b.contact_id 
         JOIN tContract c ON a.dealer_id = c.dealer_id 
         JOIN tCompany d ON c.company_id = d.company 
         JOIN tlkOrigDept E ON c.orig_dept_id = e.orig_dept_id 


  WHERE c.orig_dept_id = 2 
         And d.company_id = @program 
         AND c.Funded_date  &gt;= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-5, 0) 
         And YEAR(c.Funded_date) = @Year 
         And c.Funded_date &lt; DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, 0) 
         And (c.funded_date) between @Begin_Date And @End_Date 


   GROUP BY
    d.name,
    a.dealer_code,
    b.last_name,
    b.city,
    b.state,
    b.phone,
    MONTH(c.funded_date),
    Month(e.orig_dept_name),
    e.orig_dept_name
      end



    exec spGetAdminServiceYTD '01/01/2014', '05/30/2014', '47'
```

Comment: Does the value ('F&I') have corresponding rows in all the other tables?  If not, you won't get rows back, since you're using inner joins.

Comment: What does "It just shows blank" mean exactly? Is there an empty result set?

Comment: For the ('F&I') it shows results but for 1 company when I input "47" for the program. If I try to input any other program I get a empty result set. And Yes Martin I meant Empty result set when ever I execute. Also if I set the c.orig_Dept_Id = 2 I get Empty result set for all the companies. But when I set c.orig_Dept_Id = 3 The company '47' only works for some reason and no other @program will work. I have been trying to figure this out all day.

Comment: Are the January and February counts supposed to come from the Dept ID or from the funded date like everything else?

Comment: Oh ignore that I was suppose to put (c.funded_date) instead of (c.orig_Dept_ID) just like for the rest of the months.

Comment: Drop your WHERE conditions, see what result you get then start adding the WHERE condition one by one and re-check the result after each new condition. So you can see which combination of WHERE conditions gives you results and which new condition will blank the set. Basically, an empty result set means there are no rows which fulfill the conditions.

Comment: Have you tried Martin K's suggestion and if so, what happened?  Edit your original post to show this new information.

Comment: @user3753188 Can you create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with your tables and some sample data?

Comment: Thanks but I found out my answer. I decided to add another parameter called type. And I added it to my Where clause. (WHERE c.orig_dept_id = @Type And d.company_id = program...etc)